# Python Bot unable to execute in .EXE but works good in my IDE

Tags: python, selenium, bots, geckodriver

My project folder

```
MyProj/ 　
  ├ driver/ 　
  │　└ geckodriver.exe 　
  └ main.py
```

main.py

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
    import time
    import os
    import sys
    
    def resource_path(relative_path):
        try:
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
        except Exception:
            base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
    
    class InfermedicaBot:
      def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(resource_path('driver'))
    
      def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://example.com/login')
        time.sleep(2)
        email = bot.find_element_by_name('username')
        password = bot.find_element_by_name('password')
        email.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)
        password.submit()
        time.sleep(5)
        
    
    site = InfermedicaBot('username', 'password')
    site.login()
```

Pynstaller command to build exe

```
pyinstaller main.py --onefile --noconsole --add-binary "driver\geckodriver.exe;driver"
```

I would really appreciate your help, cause I've been having a hard time trying to create a functional executable file!

Comment: What error is thrown? Please [edit] your question and add the error message.

Comment: Thanks, there's no error message, but it's unable to execute .exe file

Comment: "Unable to execute" means what exactly? Just no output and the exe closes instantly? Then add some `print` to see how far the programm runs?